# Binomial coefficient paths?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Here's a problem and my attempt to answer it:

We want to get a binomial coefficient identity depending on grid walking. Starting from the bottom left corner and going to the top right corner. You can only move 1 step up and 1 left right. There are n rows and m columns in the grid. Any particular path has to use only 1 edge in the k-th column. Depending on which of the n+1 edges used, classify your paths. E.g. the blue lines, has n = m = 10 and k = 4 (if we count from 0). Then, the identity will be:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} f(n,m,k,i)  $$ = $m+n\choose n$

Find out the value of f(n,m,k,i). What is the identity for the picture below?

[image: binomial]

What do you think of my answer **here**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems to be correct. I don't how to derive your solution, but here's my insight. Note that to find the total number of ways passing through one blue segment in the $k-$th column and $i-$th we can split the way into two smaller pieces. Eventually you have to lend at the intersection of the $k-$th vertical line and $i-$th horizontal line (bottom one and the left-most one are 0). The total number of ways is

$$Y = \binom{k+i}{k}$$

Then we have to go one step right and we find all the ways from the intersection of the $(k+1)-$th line and $i-$th line. The total number of ways is:

$$Z = \binom{m-(k+1) + (n-i)}{n-i}$$

Now just multiply the two results.